# How can universal image loader be used to set image to other views other than ImageView?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, imageswitcher

I need to set an image to an ImageSwitcher by downloading it from server. But the universal image loader seems to take ImageView as a parameter.

I read that we can use ImageAware to display image on any android view.

Can someone help me how to go about this ?

Thanks,
Sneha

Comment: Sneha, I dont know much about Universal Image Loader, but I think Android Query will work with this I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loadImage` instead. That will get you a bitmap that you can use to do whatever you want with it.

```
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and return Bitmap to callback
imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
    }
});
```

Comment: Oliveria: Thanks for your quick response! It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You also can wrap your view with `ImageAware` interface. And then you can pass this wrapper into `displayImage(...)` method.

You can look into `ImageViewAware` to understand how it wraps `ImageView`. So you can wrap any view in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

you can check that Loader display image for **ImageAware** finally

the code displayImage(String,ImageView) is below

> ```
> public void displayImage(String uri, ImageView imageView) {
>     this.displayImage(uri, (ImageAware)(new ImageViewAware(imageView)), (DisplayImageOptions)null, (ImageLoadingListener)null, (ImageLoadingProgressListener)null);
> }
> ```

And the **ImageAware** extends the abstract class **ViewAware**,here is the two important methods in it

```
protected abstract void setImageDrawableInto(Drawable var1, View var2);

protected abstract void setImageBitmapInto(Bitmap var1, View var2);
```

check the two method implement by **ImageAware**

```
protected void setImageDrawableInto(Drawable drawable, View view) {
    ((ImageView)view).setImageDrawable(drawable);
    if(drawable instanceof AnimationDrawable) {
        ((AnimationDrawable)drawable).start();
    }

}

protected void setImageBitmapInto(Bitmap bitmap, View view) {
    ((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

so you can see that the **ImageView** use **setImageBitmap** to display bitmap,while the other view will use **setBackground**,here is my class for other view

```
public class CustomViewAware extends ViewAware {
public CustomViewAware(View view) {
    super(view);
}

@Override
protected void setImageDrawableInto(Drawable drawable, View view) {
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
}

@Override
protected void setImageBitmapInto(Bitmap bitmap, View view) {
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
}
```